# Celery tasks don't run

Tags: python, celery

Before I had everything working, I do not just do not understand what is wrong here and what my problem is.
I need your help, please.

I want all 3 of my tasks to run at the same time, but none of them really starts.
Any tips or help will be helpful.

I run Celery -  `celery -A tasks beat -l INFO`
And its type to me

```
[2021-10-26 15:35:51,539: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task monthly (tasks.get_monthly_subscribed_user)
[2021-10-26 15:35:51,717: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task weekly (tasks.get_weekly_subscribed_user)
[2021-10-26 15:35:51,890: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task daily (tasks.get_daily_subscribed_user)
[2021-10-26 15:36:01,890: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task daily (tasks.get_daily_subscribed_user)
```

Settings file

```
import os
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', broker=os.getenv('SQS'))

celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'daily': {
        'task': 'tasks.get_daily_subscribed_user',
        'schedule': 10,
    },
    'weekly': {
        'task': 'tasks.get_weekly_subscribed_user',
        'schedule': 30,
    },
    'monthly': {
        'task': 'tasks.get_monthly_subscribed_user',
        'schedule': 60,
    },
}

celery.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'predefined_queues': {
        'celery': {
            'url': os.getenv('SQS'),
            'access_key_id': os.getenv('SQS_AWS_KEY'),
            'secret_access_key': os.getenv('SQS_AWS_SECRET_KEY'),
        }
    }
}
```

And tasks file

```
import enum

from settings import celery
from queries import get_rows, get_schedule_subscribers
from utils import create_excel_file


class Schedules(enum.Enum):
    daily = 1
    weekly = 2
    monthly = 3


@celery.task
def get_daily_subscribed_users():
    users = get_schedule_subscribers(Schedules.daily.value)

    for user in users:
        result = get_rows(user)
        create_excel_file(result, user)
    return f'Success for {users}'


@celery.task
def get_weekly_subscribed_users():
    users = get_schedule_subscribers(Schedules.weekly.value)

    for user in users:
        result = get_rows(user)
        create_excel_file(result, user)
    return f'Success for {users}'


@celery.task
def get_monthly_subscribed_users():
    users = get_schedule_subscribers(Schedules.monthly.value)

    for user in users:
        result = get_rows(user)
        create_excel_file(result, user)
    return f'Success for {users}'
```

Comment: What version of celery are you using, and what is the output from the worker when the beat submits the tasks to it?